# How to ask if a job "hold" for me is still available?

Tags: professionalism, communication

I was working for two and a half years at an office where they knew I was planning on going for my masters after gaining some real-world experience.

They promised to hold my position while I went back to school on educational leave (without pay). My question is, how do I politely ask if I still have a job after not being in touch with the office for two and a half years?

Comment: The first step is contact your supervisor.  Are you sure, you were suppose to go this entire time, without a single conversation about your situation? As a supervisor I would expect at least a bi-annual conversation with you about your current progress.  *I mean you could have just joined a different company and never returned.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is extremely weird that you would have zero contact over this time period so I wouldn't keep my hopes up for the position to still even exist after all this time. I have waited for people to finish commitments before hiring them before (though not to extend of 2.5 years) and we always have been in touch along the way, keeping each other appraised.

> how do I politely ask if I still have a job after not being in touch
>   with the office for two and a half years?

Doesn't have to be more complicated than that:

> Hey X,
>
> I have finally finished my [reasons for educational leave], it was a
>   blast, I especially enjoyed [XYZ] and finished with fantastic scores
>   of [GFB] and even got accredited in [MNV]. It was truly a great time
>   of my life, and I value your help in making it happen. With the
>   educational leave now ove  I am ready to come back to the workforce if
>   the position is still open, so please get back to me so we can iron
>   out the details!
>
> Best regards,

Although I personally would be prepared to hear back "Who are you?" or any variation of "Sorry, but our needs have changed, but feel free to browse our job adverts, see if something matches".